# Is my approach to Android socket programming practical?

Tags: android, sockets, network-programming

In my android application I need to periodically send my coordinate updates to server and receive other user's coordinates (server sends this coordinates asynchroniously). In my approach I simply use AsyncTasks to send data and read from socket (every time create new AsyncTask for sending message to server and create read tasks say every 5 seconds). I use synchronized methods for actual reading and writing to socket. Everything works fine but the question is this approach good and practical or I'd better create always running background tread for reading socket and one for writing?

Comment: 'I simply use AsyncTasks to send data'.  'I use synchronized methods for actual ..... writing to socket.'. ???? That is contradictory. What do you mean?

Comment: I mean synchronize writes to socket from multiple async tasks not to interfere each other, because I don't close socket after sending message to server.